# drop down menu not returning values in email form

Tags: php, forms

I have a form with a drop down list. I receive email with a values returned except for drop down selection. It's blank instead of showing what was selected.
Here is my html

```
Item Type<span style="color: #FF0000">*</span>
<select name="items" class="items" id="items">
   <option value="0">Please Select</option>
   <option value="1">Gold</option>
   <option value="2">Silver</option>
   <option value="3">Watch</option>
   <option value="4">Electronics</option>
   <option value="5">Tools</option>
   <option value="6">Lawn Equipment</option>
   <option value="7">Guns</option>
   <option value="8">Musical Instrument</option>
   <option value="9">Car</option>
   <option value="10">Recreational Vehicle</option>
   <option value="11">Collectible</option>
   <option value="12">Other</option>
 </select>
```

and here is my php

```
    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
$servicetype = array("pawn" => false, "buy" => false);  //checkboxes
$items= $_POST['items'];

     $items= array (1=>'Gold', 'Silver', 'Watch', 'Electronics',  //item array
'Tools', 'Lawn Equipment', 'Guns', 'Musical Instruments',
'Car', 'Recreational Vehicle', 'Collectible', 'Other');
{   echo'<select name="items">'; 

     // For each value of the array assign variable name "item" 
         foreach ( $items as $key => $value ) { 
            echo"<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>\n";
         }
         echo'</select>';     
     }
//EMAIL MESSAGE DETAILS     
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name). "\r\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from). "\r\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone). "\r\n";
$email_message .= "Pawn: " . clean_string(($servicetype["pawn"]) ? "Yes" : "No"). "\r\n";
$email_message .= "Buy: " . clean_string(($servicetype["buy"]) ? "Yes" : "No") . "\r\n";
$email_message .= "Item Type: ".clean_string($items). "\r\n";
$email_message .= "About My Item: ".clean_string($comments). "\r\n";
```

Thank you

Comment: The PHP code you've shown is to display the Drop Down List Box . The issue probably is in the code where you retrieve the form values and send email . Could you show that part of the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Your html is broken:

```
<select name="items" class="items" id="items" ;">
                                              ^^----
```

Comment: I made the changes to html but that didn't correct my issue. When php sends form email I get this...                               Quote form details below.
NAME: name entered
EMAIL: name@gmail.com
PHONE: 909-555-1234
PAWN: No
BUY: Yes
ITEM TYPE:
ABOUT MY ITEM: 14kt yellow gold bracelet 5 grams..... Item type is blank doesn't show what was marked.

Comment: You need to learn basic debugging. your form has that field named `items` (plural), and in your PHP you're trying to access `item` (singular).

Comment: I had already made change to item in my original php, just copied wrong one for this. singular version is used on here now and php still not working.